# Generating a values for functions created with purrr:map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to use `purrr:map` to create empirical cumulative percentages for values of x_var in a df that are unique to each level of a factor variable.

Ideally, I'd like a result to be a long df where the columns look as follows:

levels (long)   |   x_var   |   epcd_val

Here's an example:

```
# load packs
if(!require("pacman"))install.packages("pacman")
p_load(dplyr, tibble, purrr)

# generate fake data
samp_dat <- tibble(
x_var = rnorm (1000, 0, 1),
levels = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.50, 0.125, 0.125)))

# generates a list of ecdf functions for each level
ecdfs <- samp_dat %>%
  group_split(levels) %>%
  map(., ~ ecdf(.x$x_var))
```

The resulting `ecdfs` is a list of edcf functions, which is unique to each level within levels.

I somehow then need to feed the x_var values, grouped on levels, back into this function. However, I'm stuck on how to pull it off with pipes.

Comment: Do you need `samp_dat %>% group_split(levels) %>% map(., ~ ecdf(.x$x_var)(.x$x_var))`

Comment: or `samp_dat %>% group_by(levels) %>% mutate(newval = ecdf(x_var)(x_var))`

Comment: That last example gets me almost there. I still need to pipe it in one expression. I often have a hard time thinking through how to get `dplyr` to properly after evoking `map`... `unnest`?

Comment: If you have other set of values to be passed into `ecdf` output function, use `map2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ecdf` outputs a function, so we feed the 'x_var' into the output function after grouping by 'levels'

```
library(dplyr)
samp_dat %>% 
    group_by(levels) %>%
    mutate(newval = ecdf(x_var)(x_var))
```

Comment: Thx @akrun, so there's no way to do it in a single chain w/pipes? I'm more curious than anything, though I think doing it in two steps will make the code more readable to people I'm working with.

Comment: @bfoste01  not sure what you meant.  Isn't this the expected output

Comment: Apologies for my ambiguity. So, there is no way to pipe off the `map` command in my question? Also in your answer, what is the function of the the second `(x_var)` in `ecdf(x_var)(x_var)`? I would have incorrectly assumed that `mutate(newval = ecdf(x_var)) was sufficient. Thx

Comment: @bfoste01  The `ecdf(x_var)` returns a function and not a value.  so you need to pass argument to that function to return the value.

Comment: Thick headed moment. I understand what you are saying. I’ve accepted the answer.